# How to grab text from html across lines

Tags: python

I have a html file with like following. What I want Python does is that when it see key word "Deposit to cash account", it will grab "Deposits to Cash account" of "class="s14" and the closest $number to it(12.32) of "class="s14"". Same for "Assets transfers in" with (5.34).

```
<tr style="height:21pt">
<td style="width:366pt">
<p class="s14" style="padding-top: 7pt;padding-left: 19pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;">Deposits to Cash account</p>
</td>
<td style="width:150pt">
<p class="s14" style="padding-top: 7pt;padding-right: 2pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: right;">$12.32</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:21pt">
<td style="width:366pt">
<p class="s14" style="padding-top: 2pt;padding-left: 19pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;">Asset transfers in</p>
</td>
<td style="width:150pt">
<p class="s14" style="padding-top: 2pt;padding-right: 2pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: right;">$5.34</p>
</td>
</tr>
```

I tried using FOR loop going through html by line, I used Regex to get the line with say "Deposits to Cash account" but don't know how to grab `12.32` across lines.

```
for line in htmlfile:

    if ('Deposits to Cash account' in line):
        lineClass = re.findall(r"<p (.*) style",line)   #grab "class="s14"
        print("inside for loop: ",lineClass)            
    if (lineClass[0] in line) and ('$' in line)
        number = re.findall(r"\$(.*)",line)

print("outside for loop: ",lineClass)
```

Expected result should be a Dictionary:

```
["Deposits to Cash account": 12.32, 
"Asset transfers":5.34]
```

Error message is `NameError: name 'lineClass' is not defined`

Also, "inside for loop: "Class=s14"" will be printed, and "outside for loop: " will be printed which lost "Class=s14". Feel like lineClass variable was cleaned after for loop finishes. Why is that

Comment: I'd suggest you look into HTML parsing libraries like `beautifulsoup`.

Comment: Why not use a library like [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)? HTML parsing is notoriously difficult using regular expressions, since HTML itself is not a regular language. It requires a full-fledged parser.

Comment: Yeah, use an `XPath`aware module like `lxml`.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for answering my questions. Forgot to mention that I'm using company laptop so can't install(such as pip) beautiful soup.... any way to use it without installing?

Comment: Like the others have said BeautifulSoup would make easy work of this. If that's not an option, then to address your original question, you're getting that error because lineClass is only being defined if the first 'If' statement is True. Indenting the second 'if' statement underneath the first will eliminate that, and then you can work out the rest of your issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot use 3rd party modules such as `beautifulsoup`, you can make *"poor-man"* HTML parser using Python's builtin `html.parser` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/html.parser.html)):

```
data = '''<tr style="height:21pt">
<td style="width:366pt">
<p class="s14" style="padding-top: 7pt;padding-left: 19pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;">Deposits to Cash account</p>
</td>
<td style="width:150pt">
<p class="s14" style="padding-top: 7pt;padding-right: 2pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: right;">$12.32</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:21pt">
<td style="width:366pt">
<p class="s14" style="padding-top: 2pt;padding-left: 19pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;">Asset transfers in</p>
</td>
<td style="width:150pt">
<p class="s14" style="padding-top: 2pt;padding-right: 2pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: right;">$5.34</p>
</td>
</tr>'''

from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    grab_data_fn = lambda data: None
    parsed_data = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        attrs = dict(attrs)
        if tag=='p' and 'class' in attrs and 's14' in attrs['class']:
            MyHTMLParser.grab_data_fn = lambda data: MyHTMLParser.parsed_data.append(data.strip())

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        MyHTMLParser.grab_data_fn = lambda data: None

    def handle_data(self, data):
        MyHTMLParser.grab_data_fn(data)


parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(data)
parsed_data = parser.parsed_data

deposits = parsed_data[parsed_data.index('Deposits to Cash account') + 1]
transfers = parsed_data[parsed_data.index('Asset transfers in') + 1]

print('Deposits =',deposits)
print('Transfers =',transfers)
```

Print:

```
Deposits = $12.32
Transfers = $5.34
```

However, using mature libraries like `beautifulsoup`, `selenium`, `scrapy` or `lxml` is preferred. With them, you can use rich APIs like XPath, CSS selectors etc. to grab the data easy way.